# Is there an isomorphism in long exact sequence of fibration, which arises from homotopy fiber construction?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fibration

I have inclusion of topological spaces $f:A\to B$. Then there is a fibration $E_f \xrightarrow{} B$, where $E_f$ stands for mapping path space. As I understand, $A$ is homotopy equivalent to $E_f$. Then I look at long exact sequence of our fibration. I am given that $sk_3 A=sk_3 B$, so I conclude that $\pi_2(E_f)=\pi_2(A)=\pi_2(B).$ Is it true that map $\pi_2(E_f)\to \pi_2(B)$ in the long exact sequence is an isomorphism? It would be really cool for me, if it were, however I don't manage to prove that (and I'm not sure whether it's true).

Thank you.

Comment: Just knowing the skeleton are the same doesn’t tell you anything about the map. Take a constant map for example.

Comment: @ConnorMalin ok, probably true. I included this fact, because i wanted to show that groups certainly are isomorphic, but I don't know whether specific map from the exact sequence is an isomorphism. I hoped that the facts that original map $f$ is inclusion and that we have not an arbitrary fibration might somehow help with isomorphism

Comment: Ah yes I missed this. Here is a counterexample: let $A=B$ be an infinite wedge of circles. Then the inclusion of $A$ into $B$ as all but one of the circles is not an isomorphism in fundamental groups (and will still not be when you replace it with a fibration).

Comment: Even better: add an $2$-cell to $S^2$ to form $D^2$. The $2$-skeletons are identical.

Comment: @Tyrone Wait, how do we get $D^2$ attaching $2$-cell to $S^2$?

Comment: I probably meant add a $3$-cell ;) . My original comment was to add an $(n+1)$-cell to $S^n$ (along the identity map) to form $D^{n+1}$. I'm sorry if I destroyed its intention with prepost edits.

Comment: @Tyrone So, for example, I attach $4$-cell to $S^3$ and get $D^4$. $3$-skeletons are identical. It seems to me that inclusion induces isomorphism in $\pi_2$. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Tyrone But in my case (in the post) I have identical $3$-skeletons. It seems to me, that it's enough for isomorphism $\pi_2(A)=\pi_2(B)$, isn't it? I struggle to understand whether isomorphism $\pi_2(E_f)=\pi_2(B)$ is the map from exact sequence

Comment: Ok, I've gone back and read your question in a little more context. If $B$ is a CW complex and $A\subseteq B$ is a subcomplex with $sk_3(B)=sk_3(A)$, then $B$ can be formed from $A$ by attaching cells of dimensions $\geq4$. In particular, the inclusion $A\hookrightarrow B$ is $3$-connected (so induces an iso on $\pi_2$ and a surjection on $\pi_3$).

Comment: The LES of your fibration now looks like $\pi_3F_f\rightarrow\pi_3A\xrightarrow{i_3}\pi_3B\rightarrow \pi_2F_f\rightarrow\pi_2A\xrightarrow{i_2} \pi_2E\rightarrow\dots$. $i_2$ is iso, and $i_3$ is surjective. Here $F_f$ is the homotopy fibre of the inclusion $f:A\hookrightarrow B$. We have used $A\simeq E_f$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108261/discussion-between-tyrone-and-haldot).